# How can I make a LINQ expression return into a class?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ:

```
        var questionIds = _questionsRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(m => m.Problem != null &&
            m.Problem.SubTopic != null &&
            m.Problem.SubTopic.Topic != null &&
            m.Problem.SubTopic.Topic.SubjectId == 1)
            .Select(m => m.QuestionId)
            .ToList();
```

Currently it does a select and returns a list of questionIds.

How can I change this LINQ so it returns a List

```
public class QuestionId
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does `_questionsRepository.GetAll()` return? It's not a collecton of the same class is it? If it is you can just remove the `Select(...)` call altogether

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an instance of `QuestionId` class and set `QuestionId` property inside `Select` with this:

```
Select(m => new QuestionId { QuestionId = m.QuestionId })
```

Comment: Nope, it's not working this way. `QuestionId` class doesn't contain `Problem` property. `Problem` property is defined in class which objects are returned by `_questionsRepository.GetAll()`.